# Exit code status in AIX with pipe for ansible

Tags: unix, ansible, pipe, aix, ansible-lint

```
[306] Shells that use pipes should set the pipefail option       
    roles/Auto_Config_Agent/tasks/AUTO_configure_AIX.yml:10
    Task/Handler: Define customer name
```

Does anyone know how to do this on AIX?

For linux just use `/bin/bash set -o pipefail`

`/bin/ksh` tb can you use the command `set -o pipefail?`

**Example play:**

```
# Define customer name
  - name: "Define customer name"
    shell: cat {{ DIRCUSTOMER }} | grep {{ DATACUSTOMER }}- | awk -F'|' '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d'.'
    register: customername

  - debug: var=customername.stdout
```

Comment: This is a bash-only feature. Install bash on your AIX.

Comment: Off: this 'Ansible' seems to be a typical _helping software:_ with it, you can do almost everything you could do without it -- but you have to invest a lot of work into learning it.

Comment: Installing bash is not so simple, they are corporate machines

Comment: Ansible is good for batch automation

Comment: You might already have `bash` installed, only hidden in `/opt/freeware/bin`

Comment: I will check, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With v5+ you can add a comment `# noqa risky-shell-pipe` to silence the linting violation if you know you don't need it.

Note: `306` was renamed to `risky-shell-pipe` in v5, like all the other numeric violations.